# Extra Line Feed in end of file in writeline

Tags: r

I have the following data frame (which is also data table):

> data6

```
1 44348616 1 1 OV1
2 44348616 2 1 OV2
3 44348616 3 1 OV3
4 44348695 1 1 OV4
5 44348695 2 1 OV5
6 44348695 3 1 OV6
7 44348496 1 1 OV7
8 44248192 1 1 OV8
9 44348697 1 1 OV9
```

I would like to write it to a file as-is.
I use the following commands:

```
s = paste(apply(t(data6), 2, paste, collapse=' '),collapse='',"\n")
writeLines(s, con=file("C:/MyLittleData.txt"))
```

When I look at the file MyLittleData.txt with an editor I see 2 extra lines. The last line indicates the end of the file (which is good) and before it there is an additional extra empty line. How can I avoid it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything seems fine to me:

```
## Read in the data
data6 = read.table(textConnection("1 44348616 1 1 OV1
2 44348616 2 1 OV2
3 44348616 3 1 OV3
4 44348695 1 1 OV4
5 44348695 2 1 OV5
6 44348695 3 1 OV6
7 44348496 1 1 OV7
8 44248192 1 1 OV8
9 44348697 1 1 OV9"))
R> dim(data6)
[1] 9 5
```

Run your code:

```
s = paste(apply(t(data6), 2, paste, collapse=' '),collapse='',"\n")
writeLines(s, con=file("/tmp//MyLittleData.txt"))
```

Read in your data set and count the lines:

```
length(readLines("/tmp//MyLittleData.txt"))
[1] 10
```

---

This is more a comment than an answer, but it's too large for comment

Comment: csgillespie, thanks. But if you open with editor you will see an extra line.  need to erase it for running cspade and read_baskets

Comment: I opened the file with emacs and gedit. Each had 10 lines.

Comment: Thanks a lot. If you open it with notepad++ you will see 11 lines. But  it is OK for read_baskets.